# How Routes load form server and bind in RouterModule.forChild before @NgModule execute in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I want to load Routes form server and want to bind in RouterModule.forChild before @NgModule execute.
can any one help me.

```
const homeRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: '', component: HomeComponent },
{
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: 'hero',
            loadChildren: './apps/hero/hero.module#HeroModule'
        },
        {
            path: 'product',
            loadChildren: './apps/product/product.module#ProductModule',
            outlet: 'dashboard'
        }
        ]
},
{ path: 'heroes', loadChildren: './apps/hero/hero.module#HeroModule' }
];

export const homeRouting = RouterModule.forChild(homeRoutes);
```

I want to load "homeRoutes" data from server.